# Is it possible to change the display duration of a UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I need to display a local notification and have it remain on screen longer than the default 4-5 seconds, preferably until the app itself removes it. I've seen other apps (e.g. Pandora) that manage to do this somehow (maybe a push notification?), but I can find no duration property on `UILocalNotification` or in `UIApplication` methods like `presentLocalNotificationNow:`, `scheduleLocalNotification:`, etc. Neither [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) nor any of the tutorials I've found address the display time at all. Is this something that just can't be done with local notifications?

Comment: Are you talking about notification when the app is in the foreground or when the app is in the background or when the screen is locked?

Comment: I mean when the app is in the background (or screen locked). Local notifications don't display in the foreground.

Comment: Correct. Wanted to make sure we are using the same terminology. When a notification happens on a locked screen, it will stay until the user unlocks the screen (home button or swipe of notification). So are you only referring to the notification when the app is in the background but the device is not locked?

Comment: I didn't realize local notifications would persist in the lock screen -- thanks for pointing that out. So yes, I'm just talking about background operation without being locked. I read somewhere that the banner would persist for the length of a provided sound (up to 30 secs), so perhaps a workaround to extend the display time would be to play silence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of solutions here and I would not recommend either:

1- You can request from the user to go to settings > Notification Center > your app. And change the alert style from Banner (default) to Alerts. This will present the user an alert similar to the alert presented when the app is in the foreground. The user would have to dismiss the alert versus the banner style notification that just appears/disappears. Unless this is a corporate app and you have the users buy in, I would not go that route as this could annoy the user.

2- I tested the sound clip method and yes, if you present a notification with a clip < 30seconds; the notification will stay on the (top of the) screen until the sound clip is finished playing. Having said that, if the user taps any of the volume button (to reduce the sound for example), the notification is immediately dismissed even before its end! I think though that the purpose of the notification is a gentle reminder and, lasting more than the typical 4-5 seconds goes against the norm and, it might annoy the user (or the user might think something is stuck, phone froze, etc..). Here is the code anyway:

```
UILocalNotification *howLongCanANotificationLast = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
howLongCanANotificationLast.alertBody=@"I am a notification";
howLongCanANotificationLast.soundName=@"musicfilename.mp3";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:howLongCanANotificationLast];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I think the bottom line is, if Apple wanted you messing with the duration of those pop-ups, they'd give you some obvious way to do it and any work-arounds might just derail your approval.

Comment: hey, I have a 30 seconds sound but the notification disappears after 5 seconds what could be the problem?

Comment: The same issues is happening to me. the local notification doesn't obey the sound duration in iOS 10.2.

Comment: If the notification is shown as banner (which is default), the sound duration isn't respected for some reason. Otherwise, if the user changes it to alert, the sound is fully played.