# Increase time duration of notification banner in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Actually I am developing an app in which pop-up generated at scheduled time but my client want to increase the time duration of notification banner which is displaying when app is running in background. 
thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the display duration of a UILocalNotification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650613/is-it-possible-to-change-the-display-duration-of-a-uilocalnotification)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If you need a notification to be more intrusive than a banner, use an alert.

Comment: Problem is that you cannot use an alert if you app is in the background. So it is just going to be banner.