# local notification banner duration

Tags: swift

How could I make my local notification default type as "alert" if my app is in background, or if it isn't possible then can I increase the banner duration, because notification just displays for 2 or 3 seconds.

I am working on alarm app, So I need my notification not to stop atleast for 30-40 seconds.

Comment: I think you can not change the type by code. its in user's hand. User only change it from settings page.

Comment: And you can not change the time duration as well, sadly

Comment: Check this url please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650613/is-it-possible-to-change-the-display-duration-of-a-uilocalnotification

Comment: You can generate multiple notifications, for 30-40 seconds.